# Merge multiple rows in single row in mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have a mysql view on which 1 column is repeated on 4 rows but the other column has different values. I want to merge all 4 rows into 1 by giving columns custom names.

[image]

Example:

I have `Long_Desc` repeated in 4 rows with different `Nutr_Val` and `Nutr_No`. I want to combine all 4 rows so the table will look like

```
NDB_No | Nutr_No | Nutr_Val | Long_Desc | PROCNT | FAT | CHODCDF | ENERC_KCAL
```

So I have `Nutr_Val` adjusted in those last 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    t.nbd_no,
    t.nutr_no,
    t.nutr_val,
    t.long_desc,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.tagname = 'PROCNT'     THEN t.fdgrp_cd END) PROCNT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.tagname = 'FAT'        THEN t.fdgrp_cd END) FAT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.tagname = 'CHODCDF'    THEN t.fdgrp_cd END) CHODCDF,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.tagname = 'ENERC_KCAL' THEN t.fdgrp_cd END) ENERC_KCAL 
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY
    t.nbd_no,
    t.nutr_no,
    t.nutr_val,
    t.long_desc
```